# Zabbix Discovery JSON values

Tags: powershell, zabbix, discovery, agent

I have multiple Zabbix agents (Windows agent) and I need to check software license's details on each agent via a localhost JSON URL.

On each agent we can see license information on local web URL like this http://localhost/license/GetAllActiveLicenses
And this URL shows details in JSON format like this:

```
{"GetAllActiveLicenseResult":
    {"Licenses":[
        {"LicenseName":"ImageServer","Enabled":true,"Remaining":"383 Day","StringExpireDate":"27-4-2020 00:00:00"},
        {"LicenseName":"WebReview","Enabled":true,"Remaining":"383 Day","StringExpireDate":"27-4-2020 00:00:00"},
        {"LicenseName":"Portal","Enabled":true,"Remaining":"774 Day","StringExpireDate":"23-5-2021 00:00:00"}
    ]}
}
```

I need to create a discovery rule to read each license field.

Comment: Is this an actual output of the service? It's not valid JSON.

Comment: anyway this is my url output. are you have any recommendation ?

Comment: You don't state what's not working. I won't write the zabbix template/item for you, just wanted to point out that your posted information is no valid JSON array, so that might cause some trouble.

Comment: Maybe i can generate vali json data, But i need help to create discovery rule for this. Can you help me about this ?

Comment: Looks like the only thing messing up the JSON is the missing doublequote before the second "Remaining".

Answer (score 0):

This site is not geared towards writing solutions for you, but we can look at the possible approaches to solve this.

- If you have Zabbix 4.2 or later, you can use [pre-processing in LLD rules](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/introduction/whatsnew420#preprocessing) to turn this JSON into a [Zabbix LLD JSON](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#creating_custom_lld_rules) (after ensuring it is a valid JSON, see comments on the question).
- If you have an older version, you might need a script to perform that conversion.